# Solve for $a$ in $(a+1)\log_2(\sqrt{a}) < 100$, $a>1$

Tags: calculus

$$(a+1)\log_2(\sqrt{a}) < 100$$,

$a>1$

I did $$(a+1)\log_2(\sqrt{a}) < 100 \Leftrightarrow \log_2(a^{\frac{a+1}{2}})<100 \Leftrightarrow 2^{100} > a^{\frac{a+1}{2}} \Leftrightarrow ???$$

What do I do next?

Answer (score 1):

In the reals you won't find a nice analytic solution.  The best you can do is numerical approximation.  To get a start, you can rewrite it as $\frac 12(a+1)\log_2a \lt 100$, then think that $\log_2a$ is slowly varying and think about an iteration.  Write it as $a_{i+1} \lt \frac {200}{\log_2a_i}-1$, guess a value for $a_0$ and iterate to convergence.  To me, it feels like $a$ should be somewhere not to far from $50$.  I made a spreadsheet and it converged to $a \lt 37.30474$ rather quickly

Answer (score 0):

*This may be too complex.*

Assuming $a>0$, consider the function $$f(a)=(a+1)\log_2(\sqrt{a}) - 100=\frac 12(a+1)\log_2(a)-100=\frac{(a+1) \log (a)}{2 \log (2)}-100$$ Its derivative is given by $$f'(a)=\frac{a(1+ \log (a))+1}{2a \log (2)}$$ which cancels at $a_*=-\frac{1}{W(-e)}$ where appears Lambert function; however, since the argument is $<-\frac 1e$, $a_*$ is a complex. This makes the derivative to be always positive and only one root may exist.

Since the function will not show explicit solutions, numerical methods are required. Using Newton for example and starting from very far, we should have the following iterates 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & a_n \\
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 70.314718 \\
 2 & 39.051310 \\
 3 & 37.312968 \\
 4 & 37.304734 
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is the solution for eight significant figures. For sure, starting closer to the solution would require much less iterations.

So, as long as $0 < a < 37.304734$, the inequality will hold.

Being less lazy, we could have used inspection writing $a=2^k$ which would give $$f(k)=\frac k2 (2^k+1)-100$$ and notice that $$f(4)=-66 \qquad f(5)=-\frac{35}{2}\qquad f(6)=95$$ which allows us to thing that the solution is  close to $2^5=32$. Using $a_0=32$ would make Newton method converging in two iterations for the same accuracy as above.